# ApplicationContextInitializer loaded twice by Spring Cloud Bootstrap context & Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

When declaring initializers in `spring.factories` file to create Spring Boot starters, we realized that those initializers were loaded twice :

- once by the Spring Cloud Boostrap Context
- once by the Spring Boot context

In our case, we start databases in docker containers, so we don't want to do it twice.

According to this issue, this is Spring Cloud's expected behavior : https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1151

When asking how the boostrap context should be distinguished from the "regular" application context, the answer given is to

> Check the ID of the context.

After running a sample application, `ConfigurableApplicationContext.getId()` returns by default :

- `application` for the Spring Cloud Bootstrap context
- `application-1` for the Spring Boot context

Some of our users don't define `spring.application.name`, others don't use Spring Cloud at all.

**Question** : How can we reliably load an initializer only once ?

If `ApplicationContextInitializer`s are meant to be idempotent, it should probably figure in the interface's Javadocs.

In the worst case, how can we safely distinguish the Spring Cloud boostrap context from the Spring Boot context ?

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue when trying to inject a property source in an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` [here](https://github.com/coveo/spring-boot-parameter-store-integration). The solution is quite simple as you only need a static flag :

```java
public class YourInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>
{
    private static boolean initialized = false;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        if (!initialized) {
            //do your things here
            initialized = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The bootstrap application context will always run *before* the regular Spring Boot application context so you can also use that to run your code in the right place.

Finally, the bootstrap context gets instantiated in `BootstrapApplicationListener`. From there, you can see that the `spring.application.name` property gets set to the value of `spring.cloud.bootstrap.name` or `bootstrap` as a fallback. This then gets set to the id of the application context in `ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer`. You could also use that to determine in which context your initializer is running against.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap context is created by `BootstrapApplicationListener` that will also set the bootstrap context as parent context. Therefore you can rely on that:

```java
public class CustomApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
  public void initialize(final ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    if (applicationContext.getParent() == null) {
      //  Spring Cloud Boostrap Context
    } else {
      // Spring Boot context
    }
  }
}
```

If the purpose of the `ApplicationContextInitializer` is to add a custom `PropertySource` it's also possible to check if the `Environment` already contains the source:

```java
public class CustomApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

  public static final String PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME = CustomApplicationContextInitializer.class.getName() + ".source";

  public void initialize(final ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {

    final MutablePropertySources sources = applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources();

    if (!sources.contains(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME)) {
      final Map<String, Object> source = new LinkedHashMap<>();
      // TODO: add properties
      sources.addLast(new MapPropertySource(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME, Collections.unmodifiableMap(source)));
    }

  }
}
```